# How to send email using mautic api?

Tags: email, mautic

I am working on an angular project. To send email through `mauticI` am writing a function in the `mautic.js` file.

```
POST /emails/ID/contact/CONTACT_ID/send\
```

In the `options.url` what should be in place of **ID.\**
I tried email address but didn't receive the mail.

Answer (score 1):

First you need the numerical contact ID for a given email address contact.

`GET /api/contacts?search=email:emailToSearch`

Then you can get the `id` from the result and send the email.

Consider also advanced filtering if you want to specify via array of field values: https://developer.mautic.org/#list-contacts